# In Maxima how do I get the row sums of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, maxima

e.g.
matrix:

```
a b c 
d e f 
g h i

->
```

column vector

```
a+b+c
d+e+f
g+h+i
```

I can think of ugly solutions with sum, and maybe less ugly solutions with multiplying by a row vector, but is there a nice way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix is represented as a wrapper around a collection of lists, where each list is a row. So mapping over the arguments of `matrix` is mapping over the rows. You can do something like this: `map(lambda([r], [lsum(x, x, r)]), A)` where `A` is your matrix.